# Query relating to split_part() in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with first_name, last_name and name.  Name consists of a full name such as "Joe Bloggs".  I want to update every row in the table with first_name and last_name derived from the name column, but I just cant find the right combination of update with subquery to make it work.

I have tried using:

```
update users a set a.first_name = subquery.first_name_new
from (select username, split_part(name, ' ',1) as first_name_new from users) as subquery
where a.username = subquery.username
```

I can see why this isn't working, but I just cant find the right combination.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows :

```
update users
set first_name = split_part(name, ' ',1),
     last_name = split_part(name, ' ',-1)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uOHG0OuE)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
update users
set first_name = split_part(name, ' ', 1),
     last_name = split_part(name, ' ', -1)
```